# Proper validation of the Name entered by a user

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate the Name entered by a user. I need to make sure the Name entered is 'literally' valid. I tried many regular expressions within my limited knowledge, none of them seem to work fully. For example `/^[^.'-]+([a-zA-Z]+|[ .'-]{1})$/`

Since the PHP website I'm working on, is fully in English, only English names are allowed.
The rules applicable to filtering the *name* are:

1. A name may contain any of these characters: `[a-zA-Z .'-]`
2. The name may **start only with an Alphabet or an Apostrophe**
3. Any of the characters in **`[ .'-]` may not occur more than once** in a stretch, ie., no '---' or '--'
4. A **space should not follow `-` or `'` nor come immediately before `.` or `-`**

Can anyone please provide the proper regular expression to implement these?

Comment: What about Hebrew, Arabic, Russian,... names?

Comment: @CommuSoft For now, those names are not to be considered. Names should be entered in English. The whole website is in English anyway.

Comment: What language (PHP, Java, JavaScript, ...)?

Comment: @Marvin PHP. I'm using preg_match()

Comment: "Most of the available methods are not foolproof"  That's because there are no methods that are foolproof.

Comment: @Andy Lester I agree. But when in a obvious case like this, there could be a good way to avoid most of the attacks or blunders. The accepted answer still might not be the best way. I'll keep updating it as more loopholes are found. :)

Comment: @Andy Lester I edited the question to respect that comment. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex to solve your problem (demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hL5kQ8/2)):

`/^(?!.*(''|  |--|- |' | \.| -|\.\.|\n))['a-z][- '.a-z]*$/gi`

Breakdown:

`(?!.*(''|  |--|- |' | \.| -|\.\.|\n))`  negative lookahead to ensure that no doubled characters are found

`['a-z]` start with one of these characters

`[- '.a-z]*` the rest can also include spaces and dashes, and are not required (`*` instead of `+`)

Comment: @KevinB: thanks, I didn't notice that requirement. I've updated the regex.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. It works. I just changed it to suit the edited question : `/^(?!.*(''|  |--|- |' | -| \.|\.\.))['a-z][- .'a-z]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
/^'?([a-z]+((\. )|( ')|['\- \.])?)+$/i
```

[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vW7cL5/2)

Explanation:

- `'?` Optionally start with an apostrophe
- `([a-z]+((\. )|( ')|['\- \.])?)+` Afterwards allow `1-n` groups of at least 1 alphabetic character, followed by certain (both) valid combinations of special characters. These are `". "`, `" '"` (quotes to see the spaces) or any single special character.
- `/i` Match case insensitive, otherwise you'd just specify `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[a-z]`.

I am not sure if `John,.Doe` or `'` should be considered valid names. With my expression they would not.

Comment: It works except when a space follows '.' eg: `John Doe M. R.`. Also a name like `O 'Brien` must be allowed.

Comment: Now it works perfect. I compared it with the two answers and found the answer by Brian, maintained lesser number of steps most of the test cases. So, I selected that as the right answer. Thanx again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get better performance by limiting all the backtracking a giant assertion would have to do.

Something like this..

```
 #  (?i)^(?=[a-z'])(?:[a-z]+|([ ](?!-)(?<!'[ ])|[.'-])(?!\1))*$

 (?i)                 # Modifier, case insensitive
 ^                    # BOS
 (?= [a-z'] )         # Starts with an alpha or apos '

 (?:                  # Cluster
      [a-z]+               # 1 to many alpha's
   |                     # or
      (                    # (1 start), Capture group, one of [ .'-]
           [ ]                  # Single space
           (?! - )              # not a dash - ahead
           (?<! ' [ ] )         # nor apos space '[ ] behind
        |                     # or,
           [.'-]                # Single dot . or apos ' or dash -
      )                    # (1 end)
      (?! \1 )             # Backref capt grp 1,
                           # not adjacent duplicate of one of [ .'-]
 )*                   # Cluster end, do 0 to many times
 $                    # EOS
```